# Retrieving the value from a url, php

Tags: php

this is my first post. So basically I am trying to make a php file that returns the value of a website.

Here's what I got so far:

```
<?php
function GetRank($userId,$groupId) {

    $url = "http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=GetGroupRank&playerid=$userId&groupid=$groupId";
    //echo $userId,$groupId;

    //$response = readfile($url); // works but returns this (READ HERE)'<Value Type="integer">1337</Value>32'

    if ($response) {
        return $response;
    }
    return 'Failure';
}
?>

<Value Type="integer">1337</Value>32
```

I don't want to have it returning the above, as it currently does, I wanted it to return 1337. No clue how, I never did this before.

An example link:
http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=GetGroupRank&playerid=25608009&groupid=228876

Thanks in advance I hope u guys understand me q.q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below which will remove html tags from a string.

strip_tags($response);